# Каким образом здесь действуют указатели?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Как здесь вмещаются указатели i , f ? Ведь j, g -Имена массивов.
Что идет далее -понятно. Указатели ссылаются на адреса в памяти и идет прибавление размера базового типа int(4 байта--->>> +4 за итерацию). Все это выводится.

```
int *i , j[10] ;
double *f, g[10] ;
int x ;
i= j ;
f=g ;
for(x=0 ; x<10 ; x++ ) 
cout << i+x << ' ' << f+x << endl;
```

Comment: Код должен быть текстом!

Comment: Да, сделано текстом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот тут `int *i , j[10];` у вас объявляется указатель на int с именем i и массив int'ов на 10 элементов с именем j.

Вот тут `i = j;` у вас в указатель i записывается адрес начала массива j. Указатель способен хранить адрес, что он и делает.

`i+x` и `f+x` - получение адреса элементов массивов через указатель (на их начало в данном случае). Компилер знает размер элементов массива и создает соответствующий нативный код для исполнения.

Comment: А, получается у меня выделится целый диапазон длинной в 40  (0...9 >> 10 ; 10*4 ) значений?

Comment: Так можно было...

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing каких значений? Массив j, вероятно, будет иметь длину в 40 байт - 10 элементов по 4 байта. Но зависит от размера int.

Comment: *"i+x и f+x - обращение к элементам массивов"* - нет, не обращение к элементам, а всего лишь их адреса.

Comment: Да, к адресам в памяти, если точнее. Выходит *i получает значение адреса в 40 значений(int4 байта) , а *f в 80 значений ( double8 байт), и выходит что-то типа диапазона значений, до конца которого оно будет увеличиваться.. Так?

Comment: Кажется понял. Не знал , что такое можно.. Спасибо.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing это называется "арифметика указателей". Компилятор знает размер типа данных и поэтому такие фокусы работают.